# passing a crystal report object between pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have passed objects through session variables often and have not had a problem till now.  I am trying to pass a  crystal report object to another page.  in my first pages I do:

`Session["ReportObject"] = rptReport;`

and in the new page I do:

`ReportDocument rptReport = (ReportDocument)Session["ReportObject"];`

I have used this same method for other custom objects with no issue, but for this object, when try to access it, the object is not set to an instance.  I have verified the object is instantiated before sending it.    I have seen posts about sending object using the above message.  I did see one similar post to my issue (with no replies).  is it something to do with crystal reports?

thoughts? ideas?

Answer (score 0):

took a different approach...  outputted the report to a memory stream and set that to the session variable.  then on the receiving page. I was able to access that variable and output it to the Response.

so that worked, but still wondering why I could not access the report variable.

Answer (score 0):

after passing Object in session Don't dispose that object...

```
Session["ReportObject"]=rptReport;
```

<s>`rptReport.Dispose();`</s>

You'll get object as it is...!